# UInt8 Array to Strings in Swift

Tags: arrays, string, swift, type-conversion

**I want to convert an Array of UInt8 to several strings**

```
var BytesArray = [123, 9, 32, 236]
```

**TO**

```
var Srt0 = "123"
var Srt1 = "9"
var Srt2 = "32"
var Srt3 = "236"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, the answer should be like that-

```
  var BytesArray = [123, 9, 32, 236]
  var sort0:String = String(BytesArray[0])
  var sort1:String = String(BytesArray[1])
  var sort2:String = String(BytesArray[2])
  var sort3:String = String(BytesArray[3])
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the following?

```
    var bytesArray = [123, 9, 32, 236]
    let stringArray = bytesArray.map( { "\($0)" })
    print(stringArray)
```

This will produce an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
var BytesArray: [Int] = [123, 9, 32, 236]

var stringArray = BytesArray.map
    {
        String($0)
}
```

`stringArray` will become `["123", "9", "32", "236"]`